# haml bootstrap navbar issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haml, navbar

I have a navbar in haml code but when i resize the screen i can see my toggle  button, but if i click on it my nav items won't show up. Any idea what can be wrong ? I added the CSS code below too on request.

```
    %nav.navbar.navbar-fixed-top{role: "navigation"}
      .container-fluid
        .navbar-header
          %button.navbar-toggle{"data-target" => ".navbar-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse", type: "button"}
            %span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar

          .navbar-brand 
            = link_to "TRAVVLR", root_path

        .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-collapse
            %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
              %li= link_to "Login", "#login"
              %li= link_to "Sign up", "#sign_up"
              %li= link_to "Help", root_path
```

The css i have in total is:

```
// Page styling 

h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

// Navbar Styling 

.navbar-brand {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px !important;
}

.navbar-brand > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-bar {
   background-color:#000 !important;
}

// Jumbotron Styling

.jumbotron.vertical-center {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.vertical-center {
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align : center;
    -webkit-align-items : center;
    -moz-box-align : center;
    -ms-flex-align : center;
    align-items : center;
    -webkit-box-pack : center;
    -moz-box-pack : center;
    -ms-flex-pack : center;
    -webkit-justify-content : center;
    justify-content : center; 
}

.jumboContent {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I converted your haml to html and checked just now. It seems so be working fine Bjorn. Can you post your css too??

Comment: i edited my post with the css

Comment: i found out what it was, forgot to add //= require bootstrap-sprockets in my ruby application.js :/

Comment: Oh ok. Was wondering why its not working